# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar una imagen desde front-end por otra?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente código en el que deseo que los visitantes puedan cambiar el texto (ya lo hice) y que también puedan cambiar la imagen por defecto. **No necesito que se puedan guardar los cambios**, sé que si se refresca la página los cambios se pierden, esto no es problema.

¿Es posible hacer esto tal vez con un `input type="file"` oculto dentro de la imagen por defecto?

He visto páginas donde inclusive es posible copiar la imagen desde el PC y luego pegarla en el espacio por *default* sin más acciones.

Muchas gracias!

```css
.profile-pic {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url("https://academicos.uchilefau.cl/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/no_avatar15.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container wrapper image-cropper">
  <div class="profile-pic"></div>
  <h1 contenteditable="true" maxlength="9" class="ngt text-uppercase mb-0 effect-shine" style="padding: 2rem 0;">NOMBRE</h1>
  <h3 contenteditable="true" class="font-weight-light mb-0" style="padding-bottom: 2rem;">Cargo</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay una forma que en **javascript** tendrias que subir el archivo temporalmente de la siguiente manera: En html tendrias que tener un parrafohasta que cargues la imagen y insertando una etiqueta IMG por **javascript** unicamente se subira al navegador no al servidor.

```
<form method="post" >
    <input type="file" onchange="preview(this)" />
</form>
<p id="prev"></p>
```

En el javascript  tienes que tener una funcion la cual resiva el parametro que enviastes y usar el tipo files para leer el valor que contenga, despues verificar que sea una imagen si no lees la imagen y la cargas directamente al html insertandole a una etiqueta  y al final leer en donde se encuentra el archivo dentro de tu disco duro todo esto se agrega de manera local ya que lo unico que hace es leer localmente y mostrarla en el navegador

```
 function preview(ruta)
{
    if(ruta.files && ruta.files[0])
    {
        if (ruta.files[0].type.match('image.*')) {
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function(ruta) {
                document.getElementById("prev").innerHTML="<img src='"+ruta.target.result+"'>";
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(ruta.files[0]);
        }else{
            document.getElementById("prev").innerHTML="No es una imagen";
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te funcione es algo viejo el codigo espero que te sirva yo te recomiendo que lo implementes la mejor manera de cambiar una imagen es hacerla invisible y agregar una imagen nueva

Comment: Gracias, cómo podría implementarlo a lo que ya tengo armado? La plantilla que tengo no se puede modificar por ordenes del cliente :3

Comment: Hola LauraZ podrias utilizar un metodo en un javascript que te detecte un clic en cierto componente, pero lo mas sano es avisarle a tu cliente que eso necesitas poner  algo podrias usar una etiqueta a y abrir el cuadro de diaologo y pree mostrarla es el problema, si no tienes componente que te deje llamar el metodo no se como puedas hacerlo o en cierto caso podrias agregar con java script una etiqueta HTML